# I want to extract names for each topic and names for each video

Tags: python

I have the following code which seems that does not work like i want :

```
import pathlib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import sys
import os
import lxml.html
url = sys.argv[1]
page = requests.get(url)
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)
names = tree.xpath('//div[@class="cd-timeline-block"]/text()')
names = filter(lambda n: n.strip(), names)
table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('?:/'))
for index, name in enumerate(names, start = 1):
print('/{}.{}'.format(index, name.strip().translate(table)))
```

So i want to extract names for each topic and names for each videos that are in that topic and get this output from the print command. The format should be like this :

```
/0.Project Tools & Documentation/1.Organizational Change
/0.Project Tools & Documentation/2.Project Management Tools
/0.Project Tools & Documentation/3.Project Documentation
/0.Project Tools & Documentation/4.Vendor Documentation
```

After the first topic is done then go the next one and another output with the next topic and videos :

```
 /1.Glossary/1.Review of Terms & Acroynms
 /1.Glossary/2.Review of Formulas
```

And after i extract this, i also want to extract "href" links :

and print it like that :

```
  https://streaming.ine.com/play/dfdf64b8-30a5-4bce-8ade- 
  a09ec56bcd6d/vendor-documentation
```

The page from where i want to extract this informations is :

https://streaming.ine.com/c/ine-comptia-pk0-004-project-plus

Thanks!

Comment: Man, your imports are a mess. You don't even use BeautifulSoup, and import lxml twice. Can you try to condense the code to the exact minimal amount of lines needed to show the behavior that you experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url = "https://streaming.ine.com/c/ine-comptia-pk0-004-project-plus"
import requests
page = requests.get(url)
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser') 
listed = soup.find_all('div',class_="cd-timeline-block")

for i,sth in enumerate(listed):
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(sth.encode().decode('utf-8'))
    main_title = soup1.find_all('div',class_="cd-timeline-topic")[0].contents[0]

    sub_list = soup1.find_all('div',class_="cd-timeline-level")
    for j,elem in enumerate(sub_list): 
        temp = elem.contents[2].rstrip().strip('\n') 
        temp = re.sub(' +', ' ', temp)
        print("/%s.%s/%s.%s"%(str(i),main_title,str(j),temp[1:]))
```

It's important to understand how BeautifulSoup structures your HTML page, then using standard data structures such as lists.

Output is:

```
/0.Overview/0.Course Introduction
/1.Project Basics/0.What is a Project?
/1.Project Basics/1.Project Roles & Responsibilities
/1.Project Basics/2.Project Phases
/1.Project Basics/3.Cost Control
/1.Project Basics/4.Organizational Structures
/1.Project Basics/5.Project Schedules
/1.Project Basics/6.Agile
/1.Project Basics/7.Project Resources
/2.Project Constraints/0.Contraints
/2.Project Constraints/1.Risk Management
/3.Communication & Change Management/0.Communication Methods :: Overview
/3.Communication & Change Management/1.Use of Communication Methods
/3.Communication & Change Management/2.Communication Triggers
/3.Communication & Change Management/3.Change Control Processes
/4.Project Tools & Documentation/0.Organizational Change
/4.Project Tools & Documentation/1.Project Management Tools
/4.Project Tools & Documentation/2.Project Documentation
/4.Project Tools & Documentation/3.Vendor Documentation
/5.Glossary/0.Review of Terms & Acroynms
/5.Glossary/1.Review of Formulas
/6.Exam/0.Exam Preparation
```

Comment: Ok, i've manage to insert ".mp4" to each video name but still i can't remove special characters from the names. And i would like to improve this script so it will extract names for folders and videos and after that, it will create a folder with the course name and in that folder will create foders with the names of each section. And at last, the print output will be written into a txt file named "files". 
Thanks again for your help.